# Postgresql ODBC error : Incorrect syntax near 'on'

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, odbc

I have a query for PostgreSQL 9.6.6 that works on pgAdmin console. The original query looks like this:

```
insert into "UsageTable" ("ID", "Name", "Count", "Start", "End", "Offset")
values('test account' , 'test name' , '30' , '5/17/2018 12:00:00 AM' , '5/18/2018 12:00:00 AM' , '0' )
on conflict ("ID", "Name", "Start", "End") 
DO UPDATE SET "Count" = Excluded."Count" + "UsageTable"."Count";
```

Now I'm able to connect to PostgreSQL with my c# code. However I keep getting the error '{"ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'on'."}' for this command

This is the query in c# code

```
sql = @"INSERT INTO ""UsageTable"" (""ID"", ""Name"", ""Count"", ""Start"", ""End"", 
""Offset"")                   
VALUES('test account' , 'test name' , '30' , '5/17/2018 12:00:00 AM' , 
'5/18/2018 12:00:00 AM' , '0') 
[ON] CONFLICT (""ID"", ""Name"", ""Start"", ""End"") 
DO UPDATE SET ""Count"" = Excluded.""Count"" + ""UsageTable"".""Count""";


   MakeRetriableOperation().Invoke(cmd =>
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            });
```

I've tried the query without the brackets just 'ON CONFLICT' but I get an error about it being a keyword

Comment: Does the original raw insert query run on Postgres without any errors?

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: ya it runs on pgadmin client without errors

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `sql`? Please also update your post with the other **exact** command that you ran successfully in pgAdmin.

Comment: Read your error carefully, the `[ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]` would suggest that you're talking to SQL Server rather than PostgreSQL, wouldn't it?

Comment: @mu is too short oops yes my connection string still referenced SQL Server, I guess it got changed on accident. thanks for your help